# Hibernate hbm2ddl does not create foreign keys on SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am trying to generate foreign keys via hibernate hbm2ddl with:

```
   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

And using the following mapping:

```
   @OneToOne
   @ForeignKey(name="FK_address_nationality_id")
   private Nationality country;
```

It creates the table, with a country column but no foreign key is created.
Why might this be?

Comment: try to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create once for create FK, then switch back to update mode

Comment: I think it's related to another problem I have, it's creating the nationality column as a varbinary...

Comment: Have added another question regarding the column type, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192469/hibernate-hbm2ddl-create-varbinary-for-mapped-object-on-sqlserver-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using field access type when using field definition annotations rather than properties.

```
@Entity
@Table
@AccessType("field")
```

Especially if you are sub classing a class that uses property accessors.